# I am trying to create nav bar which dynamically updated with adding a sections to HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a navbar that is automatically updated to add a new link to a new section I creat in the HTML file

the HTML code
`<nav class="navbar__menu">`

```
<section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1"></section>
```

JavaScript code

```
function addSection() {
  const ul = document.getElementById( "navbar__list" );
  var section = document.getElementsByName( "section" );
  for ( let i = 0; i < section.length; i++ ) {
    var li = ul.appendChild( document.createElement( "li" ) );
    link = document.createElement( "a" );
    li.appendChild( link );
    link.innerHTML = "Section" + [ i++ ];
    link.href = section.data - nav;
    link.setAttribute( 'id', 'link' );
  }
  return li
}
```

it did not work and I am looking for help :((

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: This code obviously isn't correct but I don't know how make it right I just used loop (for) to make (number of links = number of section)s and append them to nabbar which I made in html file

Comment: (1) It's usually best to be more specific about what's not working. Does the link not show up? Does clicking it not go to the actual link? (2) Also, if you can provide some more context of what your html has, would be easier for someone to diagnose. (3) Lastly, if you can put it in a html/js playground like jsfiddle or playcode.io, it would be easier for someone to tinker with it and solve it for you and then post back here. But again, would be best if you clarified what's specifically not working

Comment: @Ali_Elsharkawy It is not so clear what exactly do you want. Please be specific and as clear as you can...

Comment: Yes, the link not show up
I get empty navbar

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bgro7mh1/

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, I will be more specific

Comment: I'm have a navbar which is empty in the HTML, when I add new section in the HTML file the navbar should be updated to creat a link refer to the new section which is previously add in the HTML.............. As I add new section there is a link refer to it in the navbar ,,,,,,,, and when I write this JS code there are no errors in console or VS but there
 are no links at all as if I didn't write anything

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to have an HTML document which has many sections written into it, and use js to create links in a nav area for each section.

I hope this small demo helps you understand how to accomplish this task. Let me know if you have any questions about my code!

```js
const nav = document.querySelector("nav");
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
for (const section of sections) {
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.innerText = section.dataset.linkText;
  a.href = "#"+section.id;
  nav.appendChild(a);
}
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

section {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

section:nth-child(odd){
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<nav>

</nav>
<section data-link-text="Link 1" id="section1">
  This is section one
</section>
<section data-link-text="Link 2" id="section2">Section 2</section>
<section data-link-text="Link 3" id="section3">Section 3</section>
<section data-link-text="Link 4" id="section4">Section 4</section>
```